# ViewBag Usage-ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

In my controller say `ControllerFirst` I am setting a `ViewBag` property by the below line.

```
ViewBag.PreviousPage="ThisIsComingFromControllerFirst";
return RedirectToAction("ControllerSecond", "Home");
```

Now from here:

```
public ActionResult ControllerSecond()
{
    return View();
}
```

I am trying to use `Viewbag` in the `ControllerSecond` by the following

View: ControllerSecond.cshtml

```
@if(ViewBag.PreviouPage == "SomeValue")
{
  //do this
}
```

But `ViewBag.PreviousPage` value is null.

Please let me know why its null, what could I do to get the value in my view from the `ControllerFirst`.

I have done this one using `Session`, but We don't want to sessions..

Any other options?

Comment: Use TempData, see

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753720/passing-info-to-another-action-using-redirecttoaction-mvc][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753720/passing-info-to-another-action-using-redirecttoaction-mvc

Comment: As I can see you left 's' in PrevousPage in your code: @if(ViewBag.PreviouPage == "SomeValue"), so please clarify that you've copied it from your view or you typed it?

Answer (score 3):

To answer your first question, ViewBag is a more convenient form of ViewData that uses dynamic objects rather than generic ones.  As with ViewData, ViewBag only exists for the life of a single request, thus it is only available between the ActionMethod and it's view.  It is not available between different ActionMethods.

Think of it like an intercom system in a home.  You can send messages to other parts of the home, but you can't send a message to a neighbors home.

The only other options you have are:

- Use Session
- Use TempData (which also uses session)
- Use a Cookie
- Use a querystring parameter
- Use an intermediate table in your database
- Post to ActionMethod

Answer (score 1):

[`ViewBag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) (and [`ViewData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewpage.viewdata.aspx)) are objects for accessing extra data (i.e., outside the data model), between the controller and view.

If your data have to persist between two subsequent requests you can use [`TempData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.tempdata.aspx).

However, `TempData` is by default [stored in the session](http://www.gregshackles.com/2010/07/asp-net-mvc-do-you-know-where-your-tempdata-is/).
So, if you don't want to use sessions, you could use cookies and somehow duplicate a bit of what session does for you, as [MikeSW suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992928/viewbag-usage-asp-net-mvc3/7993223#7993223).

[When to use ViewBag, ViewData, or TempData in ASP.NET MVC 3 applications](http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications)

Comment: Its also possible to change the default storage of `TempData`, but as Paolo states, the purpose of TempData is to store data until the next subsequent read, not indefinitely, so sounds kind of like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use TempData instead of ViewBag

Comment: Care to explain why the OP should be using `TempData`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cookie and somehow duplicate a bit of what session does for you.