# Certain ViewBag data accessible in _Layout.cshtml but not in View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, viewbag

In my `_Layout.cshtml`, I store some session data in the `ViewBag`, like so:

```
if (Session["SiteSession"] != null)
{
    SiteSession siteSession = (SiteSession)Session["SiteSession"];
    ViewBag.SiteSession = siteSession;
}
```

and it's been working great so far.

Until now. I have a view that displays some data and opens up certain controls to Administrators based on `ViewBag.SiteSession.IsAdmin`, and for some reason that value is inaccessible (or `null`, according to intellisense):

`RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on null reference`

Has anybody had this issue? Or perhaps knows where the problem is rooted? All help is appreciated.

Comment: Try ((SiteSession)ViewBag.SiteSession).IsAdmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had to change the way `ViewBag.SiteSession` was set to begin with.

My colleague placed that code in `_Layout.cshtml`, when the code should have been in our `BaseController` and executed during `OnAuthorization()`.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewBag` is a dynamic wrapper of the `ViewData` object (which is just a Dictionary), which is used to communicate data between a controller and its view. To this end, its a fantastic tool and extremely useful. **However, you cannot use `ViewBag` to pass data between multiple ActionMethods.**

To accomplish this, you must use `TempData`, which is stored in the session.

A previous answer to a similar question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7993403/2533772).

Comment: Yup, you posted while I was writing it. Glad you figured it out.